# alert with following picture

Tags: javascript, html

I was was wondering if I could make an alert and a picture appear then disappear  here's my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <style>


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <center><h1>Are you human???</h1></center>
        <button id="button">Yes</button>
     <button onclick="no"  id="no">No</button>
    <script>
    function no(){
        alert("Really you are interesting")

    }
```

Comment: `onclick="no"` doesn’t do anything since you’re not calling the function.

Comment: onclick="no" should be onclick="no()"

Comment: What do you mean from picture? Do you mean alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a picture in the alert box.You can achieve it by putting up an image in a div keeping the `display:none` for that and then show hide it like this

```js
function no() {
  alert("Really you are interesting")
  $("#msg").fadeIn("slow").delay("100").fadeOut("slow");
}
```

```css
div{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg">
<img src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png"/>
</div>
<center>
  <h1>Are you human???</h1>
</center>
<button id="button">Yes</button>
<button onclick="no()" id="no">No</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much ive been stuck for a very long time

Comment: @jonaleander you accepted my answer and then you removed the accept. May I know why??

Comment: Sorry accidently unchecked it

Answer (score 1):

There is no pictures in your code.
But if you mean - show alert popup window, you should add parentheses like so **onclick = "no()"**
You cannot customize alert window.
But if you want just show some picture after button click, you should add `<img>` with `display: none` to the page and `onclick` change it to `display: block`.

Comment: I know the() parentheses but i wanted a picture to appear in the alert box

Comment: or just a picture appear and then dissapear

Comment: "I wanted a picture to appear in the alert box" — The API for alerts allows only plain text. If you want an image, don't use an alert.